# I'm hoping we get a flood of Wonder Woman questions per the film opening

Tags: discussion

and implore people to regard them as my own teachers did, as a gateway to the original canon and not as an assault on the integrity of this stack.

Every question on superheroes with origins in mythology represents a mind interested in mythology, and our job here should be to educate.

just my 2 cents

Comment: @Gibet thanks for digging up the stats.  Guess you were correct (also, I have not been hearing good reports on the film itself.)  It's still worth pointing out that there is an "internet traffic" component to Stack, and the expansion to more stacks in recent years is, in part, to aggregate traffic and drive up the ranking of the overall site.  Question based on popular modern medium are going to draw more traffic to Stack Mythology than scholarly questions, thus superhero questions are quite valuable for us.